# angular modal service popup issue

Tags: angularjs

I have integrate angular modal before, but now i am getting this kind of issue when I try to open angular modal.

Here is an image related to that issue[Issue in Showing Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl0kl.png)

I am not getting any kind of warning or Error in console.

I have used this **[angular-modal-service](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service)** this package

controller-code:

```
App.controller('leadsController', ['$scope', 'ApiService', '$location', '$state', '$rootScope', 'toastr','ModalService', function($scope, ApiService, $location, $state, $rootScope, toastr, ModalService) {
```

and I am calling ModalService like this

```
 // Just provide a template url, a controller and call 'showModal'.
 ModalService.showModal({
     templateUrl: "pages/leadDetails.html",
     controller: "leadDetailsController"
 }).then(function(modal) {
     // The modal object has the element built, if this is a bootstrap modal
     // you can call 'modal' to show it, if it's a custom modal just show or hide
     // it as you need to.
     modal.element.modal();
     modal.close.then(function(result) {
         $scope.message = result ? "You said Yes" : "You said No";
     });
 });
```

but I don't know what is issue in showing pop-up.

Comment: i think its an issue with the css

Comment: @Sajeetharan, which kind of issue? can you describe me please?